# Magento 2 add product price with tax included

Tags: magento2

How can I add the product price with tax already included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please follow below steps :-**

```
1)  Set Configuration -> Setting Tax -> Calculation Settings -> Catalog Prices in "Including Tax"

2)  Set Configuration -> Setting Tax -> Price Display Settings -> Display Product Prices In Catalog in "Including and Excluding Tax"

3)  rm -rf var/cache

4)  php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: thank you sir, it works!